# In this demo,should I create a index on each column or just one Nonclustered index (Index Scan、Seek)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Test DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable([col1] varchar(2), [col2] varchar(2), [col3] varchar(2));   
INSERT INTO TestTable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) VALUES ('a1', 'b1', 'c1');
```

---

**example1(just one Nonclustered Index):**

```
Create Nonclustered Index Index_TestTable  on  TestTable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) ;

select  [col2], [col3] from TestTable
where  [col2] = 'b1'  ;
```

**result:**

```
Index Scan
```

---

**example2(two Nonclustered Index):**

```
Create Nonclustered Index Index_TestTable  on  TestTable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) ;
Create Nonclustered Index Index_TestTable2  on  TestTable ([col2], [col1], [col3]) ;
select  [col2], [col3] from TestTable
where  [col2] = 'b1'  ;
```

**result:**

```
Index Seek
```

---

**Q.** Should I create a index on each column or just one index?

**ps.** `select .. where col1,col2,col3`'s columns-order are random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided any information on why you need an index on those columns, but as a general rule of thumb, I can tell you that creating an index on every single column of your table is not the right approach.

Non-clustered index could improve your search performance but would have a negative impact on your *insert/update/delete* operation (and you could waste storage space).

If you add a new non-clustered index to the table, in practice a new table is created to maintain that index. For example if you create a non-clustered index on *LastName* column, then you would have a new table created to store a sorted list of *LastName*s with a pointer to the corresponding row. This could improve your performance if you are searching the table on *LastName* but it has a negative impact on your table update, because every time you update the table you need to update/sort the index too.

Non-clustered index should only be created on a column that you regularly search on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always going to query the table using `col2` then you need to include col1 and col3 in index you can just create an index for `col2` like below:

```
Create Nonclustered Index Index_TestTable  on  TestTable ([col2]) ;
```

Comment: thanks, but it get index scan result [TestDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12e54/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Hooman's comments. However, I just want to explain the reason why you got Index Seek in example2 as follows:

Since `TestTable` only contains three columns which are all included in the non-clustered index, their order in the index caused the differences.

In example2, since index `Index_TestTable2` has [col2] first, only a single seek is performed (based on `where  [col2] = 'b1'`). Therefore, if you remove index `Index_TestTable` in example2, you should still get Index Seek. please refer to [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143257/nonclustered-index-seek) for more details.